# trying to open c# file with mono on Mac not working

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I am wanting to learn C# on Mac, so I downloaded `Mono` and followed the step to download and run C# files but when I try opening the file with mona in the terminal. The terminal tells me that the source file could not be found.

```
csc hello.cs

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.6.0-4.20224.5 (ec77c100)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

error CS2001: Source file '/Users/Sammy/hello.cs' could not be found.
```

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: yes the file exists

Comment: macOS file system might be case-senitive, so be sure that the file is named hello.cs and not Hello.cs

Comment: I type the file name correctly each time but still doesn't work

Comment: What's the output of `ls *.cs`?

Comment: @Samuel.Canada can you answer latest Klaus' question?